# Prove that exists such $i$ that $\frac{x_i}{y_i}\geqslant\frac{X}{Y}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

> Let $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geqslant X$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \leqslant Y$ and $X, Y > 0$. Prove that exists such $i$ that $\frac{x_i}{y_i}\geqslant\frac{X}{Y}$.

I think that it could be proved using one of the following ways:

- pigeonhole principle,
- induction,
- by contradiction.

But I got stuck. For example when we try to show it by contradiction we can write that for all $i$ (if $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ is positive)

$$\frac{x_i}{y_i} < \frac{X}{Y}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n y_k\frac{x_i}{y_i} \leqslant Y\frac{x_i}{y_i} < X \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n x_j $$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n y_k\frac{x_i}{y_i} < \sum_{j=1}^n x_j $$
$$\frac{x_i}{y_i} < \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j}{\sum_{k=1}^n y_k}$$
But I don't know how it can be useful.

Do you have some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given that
$$
\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i}\ge\frac XY\tag{1}
$$
Suppose that for all $i$, we have
$$
\frac{x_i}{y_i}\lt\frac XY\tag{2}
$$
Then, multiplying $(2)$ by $y_i$ and summing yields
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\lt\frac XY\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\tag{3}
$$
which, after dividing by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i$, contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for this proof. It works at least when $y_i$'s are positive.

Comment: I misread the statement that $X\gt0$ and $Y\gt0$ to mean that $x_i\gt0$ and $y_i\gt0$. It is not true if $y_i$'s are not positive. Consider $\frac{3+2}{2+(-1)}\gt\frac42$, but $\frac32\lt\frac42$ and $\frac2{-1}\lt\frac42$

Comment: Ok, I think the statement should have more assumptions (about $y_i$'s) in order to be easier provable and not fail as in Stef's example.